# What is the point of using a cursor in a Sybase stored procedure for a simple 1 row UPSERT?

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, sybase

I am looking to re-write a legacy Sybase stored procedure that's 20 years old.

The logic seems pretty simple (an UPSERT of a ***single row*** into a table, with the only wrinkle being that unique key for table lookups can be 2 or 3 columns, based on input parameter).

The problem is, the stored procedure accomplishes this by declaring a cursor and using that instead of simply doing an UPSERT (in 2 versions - 2/3 column ones - based on an IF statement).

Is there any reason to use the cursor? Or was this just the original long-gone-developer being too fancy for no good reason?

*In case it matters, the details:*

Table has key-value pairs, stored for multiple entities. Each key can either be multi-valued or single-valued (which is in a lookup key list table, and is outside the scope of this question). Each record has an active flag:

```
entity_id int  -- foreign key into entity table
unique_id int  -- identity column for this table
key       varchar(20)
value     varchar(255)
active    char
comment   varchar(20) -- Change control audit purposes.
```

Stored procedure accepts `@entity_id, @key, @value, @active and @comment` as input parameters.

Unique key for the table is:

- `entity_id + key`, for keys that are single-valued
- `entity_id + key + value`, for keys that are multiple-valued

The stored procedure does the upsert - if the table already has the row as defined by the unique key, it updates the active flag (and the setting value, for single-valued keys).

If the table does not have the row as defined by unique key, it gets inserted.

The way I would do it would be simple

```
DECLARE @unique_id int
IF (@key_type="M") -- multi-valued
BEGIN
   SELECT @unique_id = unique_id
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  entity_id = @entity_id
    AND   key       = @key
    AND   value     = @value

   IF (@unique_id IS NULL) BEGIN
       -- INSERT
   END
   ELSE BEGIN
       UPDATE my_table
       SET    active  = @active
             ,comment = @comment
       WHERE  entity_id = @entity_id
        AND   key       = @key
        AND   value     = @value
    END
END
ELSE -- single-valued
BEGIN
   SELECT @unique_id = unique_id
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  entity_id = @entity_id
    AND   key       = @key

   IF (@unique_id IS NULL) BEGIN
       -- INSERT
   END
   ELSE BEGIN
       UPDATE my_table
       SET    active = @active
             ,comment = @comment
             ,value  = @value 
       WHERE  entity_id = @entity_id
        AND   key       = @key
    END
END
```

Instead, the stored procedure does this:

```
IF (@key_type="M") BEGIN -- multi-valued
    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR
        SELECT active FROM my_table
        WHERE  entity_id = @entity_id
        AND   key       = @key
-- next line is the ONLY difference between single and multiple value cursor
        AND   value     = @value 
        FOR UPDATE OF value, active, comment
END
ELSE BEGIN -- Single-valued
    DECLARE preexisting CURSOR
        SELECT active FROM my_table
        WHERE  entity_id = @entity_id
        AND   key       = @key
        FOR UPDATE OF value, active, comment
END
```

And then does upsert using the cursor:

```
open my_cursor

    DECLARE @cactive CHAR
    FETCH my_cursor INTO @cactive

    if ( @@sqlstatus = 0 )
        UPDATE my_table
        SET    active = @active
              ,comment = @comment
              ,value  = @value 
        WHERE current of my_cursor 
    ELSE
        -- INSERT (no cursor use, same insert I would do)

close my_cursor
deallocate cursor my_cursor
```

Comment: None really. I've seen this sort of thing before, often accompanied by "set rowcount 1".

Comment: @RichardCrossley - this one is logically restricted to 1 row... but yeah :(